# Javascript multidimensional array key - val

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my javascript function i have two single array like this:

```
var row = ["var1","var2","var3"];
var col = ["res1","res2","res3"];
```

i would create a multidimensional array like:

> [["var1","res1"],["var2","res2"],["var3","res3"]]

i tried:

```
new Array(m).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));
```

or solution like:

```
var dict = [[]];
for (i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
    e = descendents[i];
    dict[i] = dict[i][e.id]
    dict[i] = dict[i][e.value]
}
```

but the result is not correct for me. i don't know how achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: `row.map((e, i) => [e, col[i]])`

Comment: `e, col[i]` - sounds like a virus :p

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate a new array based on existing.

```js
var row = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
var col = ["res1", "res2", "res3"];
 
// iterate and generate new array based on row array element
// and fetch element from col using the same index
var res = row.map((v, i) => [v, col[i]]);

console.log(res)
```

Or with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=example) with a map function.

```js
var row = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
var col = ["res1", "res2", "res3"];

var res = Array.from({ length: row.length }, (_, i) => [row[i], col[i]]);

console.log(res)
```